# In Solidity, what does | mean in the context of "if"?

Tags: if-statement, solidity

I see an if statement in Solidity that looks like this:

```
    // Set a flag if this is an NFI.
    if (_isNF)
      _type = _type | TYPE_NF_BIT;
```

What does the `|` mean? Usually it means "or", but it doesn't make sense to me here...

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise or, a kind of [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). It can be used for example some on-off flags (indicator) for further operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bitwise or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). As the comment says, the statement sets a flag. E.g. if `_type` is (binary) `00100100` and `TYPE_NF_BIT` is `00000010`, the result will be `00100110` - i.e. it makes sure that the value of the second bit of `_type` is set to 1. This way you can store up to 8 boolean values in a byte.